# About modeling a DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I would like to create a table that represents the list of contacts of an user, but each user may have a number diferent of contacts...

I have a table **user** whith the colums **id_user, nome, info**

Each group needs contains the id of a user that is the owner of the group, the ids of the others users and other integer values for each other users.

So, the table **group** is something like

**id_dono_do_grupo, id_user_1, id_user_2, .., id_user_N, valor_1, valor_2, .., valor_N**

but this **N** may to change.

Any idea about to model this table?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest that you normalize your data model.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

- (P) means primary key
- (F table.column) means foreign key to table.column

A table for all the groups.

```
groups
    id              unsigned int(P)
    owner_id        unsigned int(F users.id)
    name            varchar(50) // Vitor's Group, Dan's Group, etc.
```

A table for all your users.

```
users
    id          unsigned int(P)
    name        varchar(50)
    info        varchar(50)
```

And finally a table tying users to groups. The owner of the group is specified in the `groups` table so this `users_groups` table lets you have as many user|value pairs associated with a group as you want.

```
users_groups
    id          unsigned int(P)
    user_id     unsigned int(F users.id)
    group_id    unsigned int(F groups.id)
    value       unsigned int // Or whatever data type the "value" is...
```

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking in something like that, but where will I put the data "value_1, value_2, value_3, .., value_N" that I need to stock to each group ?

Comment: @VitorLima - I updated my answer to address your comment. Are the values associated with users or groups?

Comment: I need to stock one "value" for each user in each group, i.e. one "value" for each pair (owner_id, user_id).
I want to mean, in each group I'll have the owner and N pairs (user, value). So, it is associated to users and groups. I don't know if I was clear...

Comment: @VitorLima Ok, I made another edit. This will let you associate as many user|value pairs with a group (which has a single owner) as you want.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understood. :)
I think that it works.
This other table will represents the relatioship between the user and the group...
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two tables to model this correctly.

The first table should store info about the group, including an FK to the owning user.

The second table should store the membership of the group. Basically to columns `group_id` and  `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an intermediary table that will be called something like `user_per_group` and have it store only the user ids and group ids so that you can then have an infinite amount of users in a single group without it changing your code.

As a general rule of thumb, if your table has a lot of columns, you are probably doing something wrong, especially if most of the columns are foreign keys.

Here is a SQL Fiddle modeling this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5179d/2

Comment: Your second paragraph is incomplete.  You forgot to mention, "unless it's a fact table in a star schema".

Comment: I hardly doubt OP is concerned about fact tables and star schemas if he can't yet model N-N relationships...

Comment: Thinking in "conceitual schema", I wanted to create a relationship between the entity User and itself.
But I have problems with the "value_1, value_2, .., value_N"